# Centering HTML elements despite max-width of outer container being reached

Tags: html, css

got a scenario whereby the max-width is being set at 1248px - however, when this width of screen is exceeded, whitespace builds up on the right hand side (where the width is now greater than 1248px) - what changes could I make so that regardless of the width (even if greater than the max-width) my inner container stays centered horizontally? I've created a small fiddle to illustrate my issue! thanks in advance!

```
<div class="wrapping-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="login">Login</div>
  </div>
</div>


.wrapping-container {
    width: 1248px;
    max-width: 1248px;
}

.container {
    max-width: 350px;
  margin: 30px auto;
   background-color: grey;
}

.login {
      width: 100%;
    padding-right: 24px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: teal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your existing code, the `wrapping-container` element *always* has a width of 1248px, regardless of the window or screen size - it doesn't make sense to use both `width: 1248px;` *and* `max-width: 1248px;` - `width: 1248px` *fixes*  the width in all cases.

What you could do (which is common practice) is to set `width` to 100% and have `max-width: 1248px;`. That way the contents will be centered on smaller screens (which they aren't right now), and as soon as the window (or container element?) becomes wider than 1248px, the contents will be centered inside the `wrapping-container` which will then stay at 1248px.

```css
.wrapping-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1248px;
}

.container {
    max-width: 350px;
    margin: 30px auto;
   background-color: grey;
}

.login {
      width: 100%;
    padding-right: 24px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapping-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="login">Login</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, it seems that you actually want to center the `wrapping-container` inside the window / screen. To do that, simply add `margin: 0 auto;` to it as shown below. (Still the two identical width/max-width settings in your code are contradictory, so I used `width: 100%` to make it useful for *any* screen width)

```css
.wrapping-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1248px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
    max-width: 350px;
    margin: 30px auto;
   background-color: grey;
}

.login {
      width: 100%;
    padding-right: 24px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapping-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="login">Login</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the width of .wrapping-container in 100%. Check the code snippet below:

```css
.wrapping-container {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 1248px;
   background: red;
   margin: 0 auto;

}

.container {
   max-width: 350px;
   margin: 30px auto;
   background-color: grey;
}

.login {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 24px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: teal;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapping-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="login">Login
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way, even if the screen width exceeds 1248px you will have your container (teal color) centered

Comment: cheers for the response - but it still doesn't help the issue if the screen width exceeds 1248px

Comment: no worries, but what you want is to have your container centered after 1248px, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following.

```css
.wrapping-container {
    width: 1248px;
    max-width: 1248px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;  /* these two properties will only make your container centered horizontally */
}

.wrapping-container {
    width: 1248px;
    max-width: 1248px;
    margin: auto; /* but this in some cases, tries to align vertically center as well */
}
```